# Multiple patterns match in a big file and track the counts of each pattern matched in perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

I have one `@pat_array` that has the user given patterns and contains special characters. Let's say `Error 78?`,  `(Not available) 77%` etc.

I need to match the patterns in the 1GB+ log file, from a particular line number to the end. I also need to keep a count of how many times each pattern was found. The code below works but it takes too long: close to 2 mins for 3 patterns.

I was thinking of a way to avoid the extra for loop while matching the patterns and do it in one shot. (Here for 3 patterns, I match $_ with three different patterns from pat_array, as you can see).

```
my @pat_array = split( '@@@', $InListOfPatterns );
my $num_pat   = @pat_array;

my @match_count;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $num_pat; $i = $i + 1 ) {
    $match_count[$i] = 0;
}

open LOG_READ, '<', "$InLogFilePath" || die "can not open file :$!";

while ( <LOG_READ> ) {
    chomp;

    if ( $. > $InStartLineNumber ) {

        for ( my $j = 0; $j < $num_pat; $j = $j + 1 ) {

            if ( $_ =~ m/\Q$pat_array[$j]\E/ ) {
                $match_count[$j] = ( $match_count[$j] + 1 );
            }
        }
    }
}

close(LOG_READ);
```

Comment: Your question would fit better on [codereview.se]. You've got working code already and want to improve it. In any case, please [edit] and include a couple of full lines of log to test against, and show us the list of patterns. If you don't want to disclose that information, write a new, full program with example data that shows the same problem, and include that. This is called a [mcve].

Comment: _when you help me with the new code/idea._ "when" means

Comment: `for ( my $i = 0; $i < $num_pat; $i = $i + 1 ) { ... }` is normally written `for my $i ( 0; $i ... $num_pat-1 ) { ... }` or `for my $i ( 0; $i ... $#pat_array ) { ... }`

Comment: *"But I was thinking of a way to feed oneself on batter, and so go on from day to day getting a little fatter"*

Answer (score 2):

The reason it takes so long, is because of loop nesting.  You're reading a list of patterns, and then trying each one, for each line.

That's very inefficient.

Something like this will do the same thing:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @pat_array = split( '@@@', $InListOfPatterns );

my $match_regex = join '|', map { quotemeta } @pat_array;
   $match_regex = qr/($match_regex)/; 

print "Using match regex of: ", $match_regex,"\n";

my %count_of;    
open my $log_read, '<', $InLogFilePath or die "can not open file :$!";
while (<$log_read>) {
   next unless $. > $InStartLineNumber; 
   chomp;
   m/$match_regex/ && $count_of{$1}++; 
}
close($log_read);

print Dumper \%count_of;
```

It complies a single capturing regex, and runs it once per line, capturing the match in the `%count_of` hash.  But it works on the *captured result* not the regex (unlike your example). This shouldn't be significant given we `quotemeta` (which works similarly to `\Q\E` to give literal patterns).

Also - there's an error with your `open` line - the precedence of `||` is too high, so it won't work. Your code functions as:

```
open LOG_READ, '<', ("$InLogFilePath" || die "can not open file :$!");
```

Which means  the `die` will happen if - and only if - `$InLogFilePath` is false (undefined or empty).

Use `or` instead, and you don't have this issue. Or add brackets.

Comment: This is fun. Your solution is about 8 times faster than choroba's on Perl Monks. But you don't allow to use the index of the pattern, like he did.

Comment: Those `\b` won't work since it assumes the patterns start and end with word chars, but at least one of the patterns (`(Not available) 77%`) both starts and ends with a non-word.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will teach you how you can profile your script to see why and where it's slow. It will use the Perl profiler [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf), which you will have to install from CPAN.

Before you do this yourself, watch [this talk](http://perltv.org/v/performance-profiling-with-develnytprof) by the author about profiling. It's important to know that this should only be done in rare cases. Your is such a case.

First, create test input with the following command, using [the JSON API of baconipsum.com](https://baconipsum.com/json-api/):

```
$ curl -s \
  'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler&format=text&sentences=100' \
  | perl -nE 'for $i ( 1 .. 10_000 ) { say for map lc, split /\. / }' >log.txt
```

This file will be about 70MB and have 1 million rows. That's enough for testing.

```
$ ls -lah
-rw-rw-r--  1 simbabque simbabque 69M Nov 28 13:36 log.txt
$ tail log.txt
Nisi magna pig pastrami, in chicken elit meatball
Consequat laborum rump kevin beef ham hock proident tempor ex strip steak
Shankle kielbasa in nulla
Consectetur picanha pork belly, drumstick tail tempor alcatra pariatur eiusmod
Tongue tail meatloaf cupim ut do sed, cillum kevin id ex dolore t-bone
Ut cow nulla brisket ball tip ipsum ham strip steak culpa cillum
Doner chicken sint duis in, andouille labore eiusmod
Bacon tempor nostrud, short loin occaecat cow nulla ipsum strip steak pastrami corned beef turducken
Ball tip labore chicken pancetta cupim
Ham leberkas pastrami, exercitation id porchetta tri-tip beef voluptate shoulder ipsum meatloaf sunt ea.
```

Next, we prepare your script. I've made a couple of changes to make it more modern Perl, like the three-argument `open` and lexical file handles.

```
$ cat patterns.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $InListOfPatterns = 'bacon@@@loin@@@steak';
my $InStartLineNumber = 2;

my @pat_array = split( '@@@', $InListOfPatterns );
my $num_pat = @pat_array;
my @match_count;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $num_pat; $i = $i + 1 ) {
    $match_count[$i] = 0;
}

open my $fh,'<','log.txt' or die "can not open file :$!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if ( $. > $InStartLineNumber ) {
        for ( my $j = 0; $j < $num_pat; $j = $j + 1 ) {
            if ( $_ =~ m/\Q$pat_array[$j]\E/ ) {
                $match_count[$j] = ( $match_count[$j] + 1 );
            }
        }
    }
}

print Dumper \@match_count;
```

This takes something like 6 seconds on my machine, and will print the number of matches for each pattern at the end.

Now let's look at how we can profile this with [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf). You just need to run this command. The `-d` flag tells Perl to use a debugger interface, and the `:NYTProf` says to use the `Devel::NYTProf` debugger.

```
$ perl -d:NYTProf patterns.pl 
$VAR1 = [
          20000,
          300000,
          90000
        ];
```

There is now a file called `nytprof.out` in your directory.

```
$ nytprofhtml --no-flame --open
Reading nytprof.out
Processing nytprof.out data
Writing line reports to nytprof directory
 100% ...
```

It will open a browser window or a new tab in your existing browser, and show you something like this:

[image: NYTProf index]

We want to go to the *line* report of *patterns.pl*. The red lines are the ones NYTProf deems very slow.

The most obvious one is the `chomp` in line 17. It is called even on lines that are discarded. Of course in our example it only skipped one line, but in your case that might be more. Move that `chomp` after the `if`.

[image: NYTProf original patterns.pl]

We can also see that the most significant time is spent on the `if`. As [chorboa says in his answer on your cross-posted Perlmonks question](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1204414), you can use a single pattern with named capture groups. I will demonstrate this in two steps so you see why he did what he did.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $InListOfPatterns  = 'bacon@@@loin@@@steak';
my $InStartLineNumber = 2;

my @pat_array = split( '@@@', $InListOfPatterns );

open my $fh, '<', 'log.txt' or die "can not open file :$!";
my %matched;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ( $. > $InStartLineNumber ) {
        chomp;

        # these two are inside the loop, which is bad
        my $i;
        my $regex = join '|', map +( $i++, "(?<m$i>$_)" )[1], map quotemeta, @pat_array;

        $matched{ (grep defined $-{$_}[0], keys %-)[0] }++ if /$regex/;
    }
}

print Dumper \%matched;
```

Let's rerun the profiler, and check the results. It now takes longer, because it does a more complex operation inside of the loop. That's bad.

[image: NYTProf patterns.pl first round]

It spent almost 2 seconds inside that loop on line 18, compiling the same pattern anew for every single of the almost 1 million lines.

So you obviously want to move this out of the loop, like choroba had in his post.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $InListOfPatterns  = 'bacon@@@loin@@@steak';
my $InStartLineNumber = 2;

my @pat_array = split( '@@@', $InListOfPatterns );
my $i;
my $regex = join '|', map +( $i++, "(?<m$i>$_)" )[1], map quotemeta, @pat_array;

open my $fh, '<', 'log.txt' or die "can not open file :$!";
my %matched;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ( $. > $InStartLineNumber ) {
        chomp;

        $matched{ (grep defined $-{$_}[0], keys %-)[0] }++ if /$regex/;
    }
}

print Dumper \%matched;
```

If we rerun this through the profiler, it reports this.

[image: NYTProf patterns.pl second round]

The call for the pattern generation is now only called once. That's significantly faster.

Unfortunately the overall win is not very high, at least with this file size. We had 12.4 seconds + 1.1 seconds for the `for` loop in the original code, and now have 12.2. Those 1.3 seconds are not quite significant with only 1 million rows. But then your file might have a lot more rows, and it will become a bit faster in total, especially if you add more possible patterns.

If we increase the patterns to five, it will be 23.6s with the new implementation, and 1.78s + 23.6s with the original one. That's a difference of 1.78s.

The benefit of having one match in the loop instead of three is very clear, but the capture group to figure out which pattern matched has its price, and the named capture group with the lookup hash created every time is even more expensive.

If we compare this instead to the solution [in Sobrique's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534467/1331451), we get 3.69s vs the original 1.78s + 23.6s. This difference is now almost one order of magnitude, which is very significant. To get the patterns with their ordinal number, you'd have to write one or two lines of additional code outside of your loop, which is negligible.

---

Please note that all measurements vary heavily from machine to machine, and are also influenced by other processes running at the same time. On your computer they might be completely different. Benchmarking is hard, and often not very accurate.